# How to set UTF-8 collation for a Azure SQL database? UTF-8 not in supported collation list

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I currently use MySQL with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and I am looking into how to import the data to an Azure MSSQL adatabase

According to this documentation;

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/working-with-collations-in-sql-azure/

It says I can only use the default `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` on server and database level, but I can change it on an object level;

> The default collation for character data in SQL Azure databases is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. This collation is also used across the SQL Azure infrastructure to sort and compare metadata that defines database objects. The server and database level collations are not configurable in SQL Azure. However, you can use a collation of your choice at the column and expression level. This article will show you how.

However, when I run:

`SELECT * FROM sys.fn_helpcollations();`

in MSSQL Server Management Studio, I get a huge list of supported collation;

[image]

But none in this list even contains `UTF-8`.

I am new to MS SQL, what am I missing? I have a hard time believing that MS SQL cannot handle UTF-8?

Comment: This should be available in azure sql by now.

Answer (score 1):

Historically SQL Server has used a separate data type [NVarchar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to store Unicode, which use UTF-16 Encoding.  For tables with Row and Page compression, SQL Server uses [Unicode Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/unicode-compression-implementation?view=sql-server-2017) so that common characters are stored using a single byte.  So currently you would convert the columns to Nvarchar, and probably enable Row compression on your larger tables.  [Row Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/row-compression-implementation?view=sql-server-2017) is inexpensive, simply using variable-width storage for all data types.

[SQL Server 2019 is adding UTF-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-ver15?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) encoding for Varchar types, mostly to make these kinds of conversions simpler.  That hasn't been rolled out to Azure SQL Database yet, but I would expect that to happen before SQL Server 2019 is released.

So you should simply pick a compatible database collation so that strings are sorted and compared similarly to that MySQL collation.  A quick look at the docs suggests that SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI might be the right collation as it's case-insensitive and accent-insensitive.  Of course, you may prefer an accent-sensitive collation, which is the default in SQL Server.

EG

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase  
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
(
  EDITION = 'Standard',   
  SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S1'
);
```

Then for any column that will store characters that can't be stored in a varchar column with that collation, change the data types to NVarchar.

Here is the list of the printable characters that can be stored in a Varchar(N) with that collation.

```
!,",#,$,%,&;,',(,),*,+,,,-,.,/,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,:,;,<;,=,>;,?,@,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,[,\,],^,_,`,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,{,|,},~,€,‚,ƒ,„,…,†,‡,ˆ,‰,Š,‹,Œ,Ž,,,‘,’,“,”,•,–,—,˜,™,š,›,œ,ž,Ÿ, ,¡,¢,£,¤,¥,¦,§,¨,©,ª,«,¬,­,®,¯,°,±,²,³,´,µ,¶,·,¸,¹,º,»,¼,½,¾,¿,À,Á,Â,Ã,Ä,Å,Æ,Ç,È,É,Ê,Ë,Ì,Í,Î,Ï,Ð,Ñ,Ò,Ó,Ô,Õ,Ö,×,Ø,Ù,Ú,Û,Ü,Ý,Þ,ß,à,á,â,ã,ä,å,æ,ç,è,é,ê,ë,ì,í,î,ï,ð,ñ,ò,ó,ô,õ,ö,÷,ø,ù,ú,û,ü,ý,þ,ÿ
```

If you primarily use a different language you can choose a different collation that will have different comparison and sorting rules, and can store a different subset of Unicode characters a Varchar column.

Comment: I am still confused, so, what does this mean in practice? Does Azure MS SQL  anything (almost) equivalent to UTF-8 (utf8mb4_unicode_ci)?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: UTF-8 for Azure SQL is coming, now in preview: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-SQL-Database/Introducing-UTF-8-support-for-Azure-SQL-Database/ba-p/735337

Comment: Link already dead... Here is what it stated:
Introducing UTF-8 support for Azure SQL Database - 
UTF-8 support is now in preview for Azure SQL Database, allowing more options to companies extending their businesses to a global scale, where the requirement of providing global multilingual database applications and services is critical to meet customer demands, and specific market regulations.

Comment: The blog and docs are now live https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017 https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-SQL-Database/Introducing-UTF-8-support-for-Azure-SQL-Database/ba-p/757748